# Loading a model with pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm having a problem loading my model in the Image Classifier project. First, I saved it:

```py
model.class_to_idx = train_data.class_to_idx

checkpoint = {'arch': 'vgg19',
              'learn_rate': learn_rate,
              'epochs': epochs,
              'state_dict': model.state_dict(),
              'class_to_idx': model.class_to_idx,
              'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict(),
              'input_size': 25088,
              'output_size': 102,
              'momentum': momentum,
              'batch_size':64,
              'classifier' : classifier
             }

torch.save(checkpoint, 'checkpoint.pth')
```

Then I tried to load the project I had saved:

```py
def load_checkpoint(filepath):
    checkpoint = torch.load(filepath)

    learn_rate = checkpoint['learn_rate']

    optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer'])

    model = models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
    model.epochs = checkpoint['epochs']
    model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
    model.class_to_idx = checkpoint['class_to_idx']
    model.classifier = checkpoint['classifier']

    return learn_rate, optimizer, model

learn_rate, optimizer, model = load_checkpoint('checkpoint.pth')
```

And I get an error when I try to load:

```
<ipython-input-75-5bd1aa042c7f> in load_checkpoint(filepath)
      9     model = models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
     10     model.epochs = checkpoint['epochs']
---> 11     model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
     12     model.class_to_idx = checkpoint['class_to_idx']
     13     model.classifier = checkpoint['classifier']

RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for VGG:
    Missing key(s) in state_dict: "classifier.0.weight", "classifier.0.bias", "classifier.3.weight", "classifier.3.bias", "classifier.6.weight", "classifier.6.bias". 
    Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "classifier.fc1.weight", "classifier.fc1.bias", "classifier.fc2.weight", "classifier.fc2.bias".
```

This seems to be classifier issue. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: It looks like `model.classifier` has changed since you saved. Specifically it looks like while you're loading, `model.classifier` is an `nn.Sequential` but when you saved your model `model.classifier` was a custom module containing `fc1` and `fc2` layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jodag's comment points at the heart of the issue. 
If fc1 fc2 correspond to classifier.0 classifier.3, classifier.6 you can adjust the dictionary to link them.
When loading the weights to the model make sure to add the option strict=False.

You will need to retrain your model for the classifier - because your state dict misses weights for 3 layers but have 2 unused layer weights - but it should converge really quickly (from personal experience).